# Firebase: update users in batch

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm trying the update infos emailVerified and password of a list of users, however I am struggling to make this work properly. I'm getting the request completed with timeout status, without been executed for all users in array.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
exports.updateUserInfo = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    let users = getUIDsToUpdateInfo();    
    let timeout = 0;

    for(let uid of users){
      console.log(`${uid}: Preparing to update user at ${timeout} ms` )

      // Once firebase not handle well multiple calls, create a delay for each call
      setTimeout(() => {
        let newPass = getNewPassForUser(uid);
        
        admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
          password: newPass,
          emailVerified: false
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`uid: ${uid} - User info has been changed.`);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(`uid: ${uid} - Fail to change user info`, error);
        }); 
      }, timeout)
      timeout += 200;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      res.status(200).send("OK!");
    }, timeout)
});
```

When uid's array is too big, (eg: more than 250), the function finish with: `Function execution took 60004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'` without execute to all uids.

Is there a way to execute all this calls in background and send response of request immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [increase the timeout of a function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) if it's going to take longer than the default timeout of 60 seconds.

If you have more work to perform than can't be finished with the maximum timeout of 9 minutes, you will have to find some way to queue up work and execute it in batches so that the http function can send a response before the timeout expires.  You might do this by sending a messages to a [pubsub function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) that for each account to modify.

Comment: Uhm, interesting. Increasing timeout can resolve my issue for now. But in future, for sure, I'll need a another way to make this work. Thanks for answering, and the links.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, if an answer was helpful, it's customary to upvote and mark answers as correct using the buttons on the left.